# issues with css height 100%

Tags: css, height

I've been looking at the numerous other questions related to this but i still can't seem to sort it out. I have a simple HTML and CSS document. For some reason i'm unable to get the content tag working correctly with a 100% height. I've been looking at parent objects i.e body and html to make sure they also have a height of 100% (which they do) but still nothing. The HTML code i'm using is as follows;

The HTML is here > http://pastebin.com/ZmJeneie
The CSS is here > http://pastebin.com/NWVdMv8i

EDIT: an example of the page can be found here > http://steelfoot.com/test/ I'm trying to get the content block to fill (and push the copyright to the bottom).

any pointers?

Comment: what do you mean by '100%' ? who's 100%?

Comment: the height of the content id div doesnt fill the page.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem using the minimal amount of html / css? Throwing up pastebin links to large files is discouraged, because it is unlikely to help anyone else in the same boat.

Comment: i already have simplified them. It's just layout with a bit of text to identify each area. I'll remove the nav though.

Answer (score 2):

Add "height: 100%;" to #wrapper. You need to have % height defined on all parents of object to make it work. Not only on html and body.